# How could I tidy this MySQL code and make it more readable?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table_1`
WHERE
    `id` = 
            (
                SELECT 
                    `an_id` 
                FROM
                    `table_2` 
                WHERE
                    `id` = 
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    `another_id` 
                                FROM 
                                    `table_3`
                                WHERE 
                                    `id` = 
                                            (
                                                SELECT                      
                                                    `yet_another_id` 
                                                FROM 
                                                    `table_4` 
                                                WHERE 
                                                    `id` = 123
                                            )
                            )
            )
```

Pretty ugly right?
I'm guessing I could use JOINs here - but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this return the same results on your data?:

```
SELECT
  table_1.*
FROM
  table_1
  INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.an_id
  INNER JOIN table_3
    ON table_2.id = table_3.another_id
  INNER JOIN table_4
    ON table_3.id = table_4.tet_another_id
WHERE
  table_4.id = 123
```

Even if it does, it's still worth benchmarking the two to see which is actually faster.

Comment: JOINs (inner, left, or right) are MUCH more efficient than sub-selects for EVERY situation I have encountered, when working with ~billion record tables.

Comment: @J Jorgenson: Agreed, I've also never seen the opposite be true.  But it's still good to validate and have some defined metrics.  Such validation also helps define healthy indexes.  And besides, the order of magnitude of the records make a huge difference.  As you say, in tables with 10^9 records, the JOIN is the clear winner.  If a table is never going to have more than 10^2 or 10^3, the difference might not be so pronounced.  In that case there may be considerations for code clarity over performance.  (Not in this case, but in similar cases possibly.)

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.*
from
    table1 t1,
    table2 t2,
    table3 t3,
    table4 t4
where
    t4.id = 123
    and t3.id = t4.yet_another_id
    and t2.id = t3.another_id
    and t1.id = an_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
FROM 
    table_1 AS t1 
JOIN 
    table_2 AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) 
JOIN 
    table_3 AS t3 ON (t2.id = t3.id)
JOIN 
    table_4 AS t4 ON (t3.id = t4.id)
WHERE 
    t4.id = 123
```

Maybe this helps you..